# Select query on stored procedure with out parameters

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I wrote Oracle stored procedure on oracle SQL developer with out parameters as below

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE "SYSLOCKDAILY" 
    Is
     BEGIN


    select * from PDB2B_SYSTEMLOCKINFO 
           where ISDAILY = 1 
             and active = 1 
             and TO_TIMESTAMP (to_char(sysdate,'HH12:MI AM'),'HH12:MI AM') >=TO_TIMESTAMP (STIME,'HH12:MI AM') 
             and TO_TIMESTAMP (to_char(SYSDATE,'HH12:MI AM'),'HH12:MI AM') <= TO_TIMESTAMP (ETIME,'HH12:MI AM');



    COMMIT;
    END SYSLOCKDAILY;
```

But I got error as below on error log. Pls help me fix this.

Error(9,2): PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PL/SQL columns of select statements must be assigned to variables using the `INTO` keyword. Try:

```
DECLARE
    v_number_of_rows int;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    INTO v_number_of_rows 
    FROM PDB2B_SYSTEMLOCKINFO 
    WHERE ...<your query>;
END;
```

In this example a **single** value will be stored in `v_number_of_rows`. If you need to handle multiple rows I recommend reading about [Cursors](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/cursors/index.php).

Comment: it is working and Thank you very much.I am new to oracle and that is why I posted this.

Comment: The `INTO` keyword goes at the end of the `SELECT` list, e.g. `select count(*) into v_number_of_rows from ...`